# Use icinga2 to Install Updates on Linux Machines

Tags: apt, icinga2

Using  icinga's (nagios'?) *apt CheckCommand* I can get warned if there are package updates available. I noticed that there is also an `--upgrade` argument in the *apt CheckCommand*.

Is it possible to perform `apt-get upgrade` on remote hosts using icinga2?
If yes, what would be the approach? I wouldn't like package upgrades done completely automatic, but rather use icinga to perform an upgrade of all hosts *on demand*.

The apt CheckCommand (Script) looks like this:

```
object CheckCommand "apt" {
  import "plugin-check-command"
  command = [ PluginDir + "/check_apt" ]
  timeout = 5m
  arguments += {
      "--critical" = {
          description = "If the full package information of any of the upgradable packages match this REGEXP, the plugin will return CRITICAL status. Can be specified multiple times."
          value = "$apt_critical$"
      }
      "--dist-upgrade" = {
          description = "Perform a dist-upgrade instead of normal upgrade. Like with -U OPTS can be provided to override the default options."
          value = "$apt_dist_upgrade$"
      }
      "--exclude" = {
          description = "Exclude packages matching REGEXP from the list of packages that would otherwise be included. Can be specified multiple times."
          value = "$apt_exclude$"
      }
      "--extra-opts" = {
          description = "Read options from an ini file."
          value = "$apt_extra_opts$"
      }
      "--include" = {
          description = "Include only packages matching REGEXP. Can be specified multiple times the values will be combined together."
          value = "$apt_include$"
      }
      "--timeout" = {
          description = "Seconds before plugin times out (default: 10)."
          value = "$apt_timeout$"
      }
      "--upgrade" = {
          description = "[Default] Perform an upgrade. If an optional OPTS argument is provided, apt-get will be run with these command line options instead of the default."
          value = "$apt_upgrade$"
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have answered this already at monitoring-portal.org but will add it here too.

Icinga is not a lifecycle management tool which actively ensures that your systems are in a specified state, i.e. package version => latest. Icinga is for Monitoring this fact and to alert a person who is responsible for the system.

The reason why you shoudn't run upgrades in an automated fashion - package updates sometimes require data migration, or service restarts. That may harm your operative business, if no maintenance window is scheduled (best example: apache and sessions, or mysql server connections).

Look into management tools like Foreman in combination with Puppet, Ansible. Katello could be interesting too in terms of package management.

https://www.theforeman.org

Comment: Hi Michi,

You did ;-)

Thank you again for your answer. Part of the question was:
_I wouldn't like package upgrades done completely automatic, but rather use icinga to perform an upgrade of all hosts on demand._

So the answer is not exactly aimed at my question. But I take this as no, there is no way to do this **manually** from within Icinga.

:-)

Comment: Ok. One thing comes to mind - trigger an event handler, which then i.e. schedules a job on your package management tool which has to be approved. But obviously if you have such a tool already (spacewalk for example), you won't need an Icinga check for it.